# Matriz de cadenas

Tags: c

estoy haciendo una asignación con matrices en C y me gustaría saber si es posible guardar cadenas dentro de una matriz, pero mediante entradas del usuario, lo he intentado caracter por caracter, pero al ejecutar no muestra nada. Aquí está mi código

```
int main()
{
    int cp = 0, i, j, ll = 50;
    char palabra[cp][ll];
    printf("indique cantidad de palabras: ");
    scanf("%d", &cp);

    for(i = 0; i<cp; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j<ll; j++)
        {
            printf("\nindique una palabra:");
            scanf("%c", palabra[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("%s", palabra[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No necesitas el bucle interno del contador j; tienes que indicar a scanf que lees una cadena, en este caso debes utilizar %s (ya que %c es para un unico carácter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando en [c](/questions/tagged/c) usas formaciones<sup>1</sup> de tamaño dinámico (tamaño que se conoce durante la ejecución del programa) debes usar `malloc` para pedir memoria y `free` para liberarla:

```
int cp = 0;
printf("indique cantidad de palabras: ");
scanf("%d", &cp);

char **palabra = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char**) * cp);
//                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- Pedir memoria para 'cp' cadenas
```

Dado que vamos a crear una formación<sup>1</sup> de cadenas, necesitaremos un puntero a puntero. Posteriormente pediremos cada palabra por separado, no es necesario un bucle anidado:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cp; ++i)
{
    palabra[i] = (char*)malloc(50);
//                      ~~~~~~~~~~ <--- Pedir memoria para una cadena de 50 caracteres
    printf("\nindique una palabra:");
    scanf("%s", palabra[i]);
}
```

El usar una variable para declarar una formación<sup>1</sup> se conoce como [Formación de Tamaño Variable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=vla+%5Bc%5D+or+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D) (*Variable Lenght Array* en inglés) y no es código estándar por lo que los compiladores no están obligados a darle soporte a esta característica. El código no estándar puede no funcionar igual en todos los compiladores puede no funcionar en algunos compiladores y puede dejar de funcionar en el futuro en aquellos compiladores en que esté funcionando en el presente. En resumen: NO USES Formaciones de Tamaño Variable.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

1. En [c](/questions/tagged/c) las funciones que no deben recibir argumentos deben definirse con `void` en la lista de parámetros, de lo contrario se considera que reciben una cantidad desconocida de argumentos, así que en lugar de `int main()` debes escribir `int main(void)`.
2. Procura favorecer el preincremento frente al postincremento, lee [este artículo](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/) para saber más.
3. Declara las variables de indizado de bucles `for` en el propio bucle; se aconseja que las variables tengan el ámbito más pequeño posible pues ayuda a entender el código y puede favorecer optimizaciones del compilador.

Teniendo en cuenta los puntos anteriores, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int cp = 0;
    printf("indique cantidad de palabras: ");
    scanf("%d", &cp);
    
    char **palabra = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char**) * cp);

    for (int i = 0; i < cp; ++i)
    {
        palabra[i] = (char*)malloc(50);
        printf("\nindique una palabra:");
        scanf("%s", palabra[i]);
    }

    printf("Las %d palabras introducidas son:\n", cp);

    for (int i = 0; i < cp; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", palabra[i]);
        free(palabra[i]);
    }
    free(palabra);

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVE9T8MwEN39K05BRU4KqBJiSQsDM0jslOFqO/Qk1w52soD624PtxKWFTmRw5Hd37@Msrt@FGIYLMkL3UsHKd5LszfaBnUCaNhFjZDrYIRlesi8G4YuAaOEeFst0b11AGl6QkfTRKxBoOpIoIRC1qHHj0NdQlGO3D@XQPJPFFVyKdkLTIbbooKqmmSDAI1JV5Q61toJ7@lS2ySBUkMbTaGMd8GiMkq/wW4XqEuZzKlPDaD3ZHelf6e2gkAXuFpOd41hrk4P1BvN0XRx15kg@RPphnxr27GRJT@hhJg97ict0VvYiLMyDt6Zem8Dyv2CTxMwnjj9OEp1Tip/x@LuW5Z3qemfiS@@H4ZY92k5pjexFOWfZszVKIvsG)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: Los VLA si es estándar, ANSI C lo introdujo a partir de C99. Ahora, el problema radica que no todos los desarrolladores de compiladores están de acuerdo con esta característica, así que depende del desarrollador si lo toma en cuenta o no.

Comment: Caray Dave, me lo has hecho buscar. En el [estándar C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (6.7.5.2 Array declarators) en el apartado 4 explica lo que es un VLA. Tienes razón: están estandarizados.

Comment: Tenía mis dudas sobre la validez de los VLA y me sonaba que se habían estandarizado para después des-decirse. Si consultamos el [estándar C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (6.7.6.1 punto 4) vemos que los VLA han pasado de ser estándar a ser condicionalmente soportados por el compilador: *(Variable length arrays are a conditional feature that implementations need not support*.

Answer (score 1):

El problema radica aquí:

```
int cp = 0, i, j, ll = 50;
char palabra[cp][ll];
```

La variable cp vale 0 y lo estás usando como longitud en la primera dimensión de la matriz `palabra`.

Debes declarar el arreglo después de pedir el tamaño por teclado:

```
int cp = 0, i, j, ll = 50;
printf("indique cantidad de palabras: ");
scanf("%d", &cp);
char palabra[cp][ll];
```

De este modo, se define correctamente la cantidad de filas que tendrá la matriz.

Ahora, si lo que quieres es pedirle al usuario que ingrese caracter por caracter, deberías cambiar el mensaje `\nindique una palabra:` por `\nindique una letra:`.

También recalco que el uso de los VLA (Variable Length Arrays) podrían causar problemas a tu programa, dado que no es posible detectar si hay fallas en la asignación de memoria. Para más información: [The Danger Of Variable Length Arrays In C99+](https://www.reidatcheson.com/c/programming/2015/12/07/vlas.html).

La manera adecuada de pedir tamaños en tiempo de ejecución, es usando la función `malloc`.

En tu programa, podríamos crear una matriz dinámica de tipo char de esta forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int cp, i, j, ll = 50;
    char** palabra;
    printf("indique la cantidad de palabras: ");
    scanf("%d", &cp);

    //Reserva memoria para las filas (que en realidad es un arreglo de punteros).
    palabra = malloc(cp * sizeof *palabra); 
    if(palabra == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: No se pudo reservar memoria");
        return 1;
    }
    for(i = 0; i != cp; ++i)
    {
        //Reservamos memoria para las columnas (que en realidad estamos haciendo que cada puntero del arreglo de punteros, apunte a la dirección base de un ARRAY DINÁMICO).
        palabra[i] = malloc(ll * sizeof(char));
        if(palabra[i] == NULL)
        {
            //Si hay una falla, debemos liberar la memoria de cada columna que se haya reservado
            for(j = 0; j != i; ++j)
                free(palabra[j]);
            //Liberamos todas las filas reservadas 
            free(palabra);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < cp; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < ll; j++)
        {
            printf("\nindique una letra del STRING %d:", i + 1);
            scanf("%c", palabra[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", palabra[0]);

    //Liberamos la matriz dinámica
    for(i = 0; i != cp; ++i)
        free(palabra[i]);
    free(palabra);
    return 0;
}
```